# TabHost in Scrollview scroll on content change

Tags: java, android, scrollview, android-tabhost

I have a `ScrollView` as parent. Inside there is a `LinearLayout` with `ImageView` and `TabHost`. I change the Content of the `TabHost` via Activities. While changing the Content, the `Tabhost` scrolls down to it's own tabs, the header is no more visible. How can I prevent this?

My main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView 
    android:id="@+id/mainScroll"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >


    <TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="800px"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="800px"
                android:layout_height="200px"
                android:src="@drawable/header" />

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="50px" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:padding="5dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </TabHost>
</ScrollView>
```

My Activity to change the Content:

```
    public class UeberActivity extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ueber);
    }
}
```

How can I avoid this scrolling?

Answer (score 1):

There was another similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36332922/android-tabhost-auto-scroll-vertically-in-side-scrollview-on-tabchange/39491500#39491500) where I posted an answer. Basically I extended ScrollView and overwrote `computeScrollDeltaToGetChildRectOnScreen`.

The reason for the unwanted scrolling is, that in `requestChildFocus` ScrollView by default scrolls to the focused view (e.g. the TabHost). `computeScrollDeltaToGetChildRectOnScreen` is used to calculate the delta scroll to bring the view in sight.

Java:

```
public class MyScrollView extends ScrollView {
    public MyScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);

    }

    public MyScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

    }

    @Override
    protected int computeScrollDeltaToGetChildRectOnScreen(Rect rect) {
        // This function calculates the scroll delta to bring the focused view on screen.
        // -> To prevent unsolicited scrolling to the focued view we'll just return 0 here.
        //
        return 0;
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<YOUR.PAKAGE.NAME.MyScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
</YOUR.PAKAGE.NAME.MyScrollView>
```